# Security Code generation's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption

Alright, here's the story:

I'm getting married soon, and I'd like to create a website (or an app).
Obviously, I'd like that **only guests** could access to it.

So I was thinking about a system where it would require a security code to sign up.
The problem is that I do not trust anyone not to be silent about the code, so I was thinking about giving **a different code for every couple (or *family*) of invited people**.

On the sign up form, I would then **verify that the entered code has not already been used**.

But since I don't know who will sign up to the app, and I don't really have time to manually register each guest, I won't have a database with *what code has been provided to whom* information.

So, I **need an algorithm to generate a *random* security code**, and **the *reversed* one, to check if a given string *is a validate security code***

I need the algorithm to be *complex* enough so people could not guess *what's the magic behing the code they received*. (I know, it feels pretty paranoid)

The generated Securiy Code should be pretty simple, like **6 to 8 characters** (mix of digits, upper and lower case letters)

---

The main issue is that I have no clue how to perform a reliable system to generate and validate a security codes.

I feel like I should have a **secret key** stored on the server side, that would be necessary to generate a code, and I would have to find it back if a given string is a valid code.

Let's say `secret` is my private key.

The generation algorithm would be something like `secret + whatever = generated code` (where the `+ whatever` operation remains to define).

But then how could I check a given string? `string - whatever =? secret` would be the solution (where `- whatever` is the reverses operation of `+ whatever`).

Well, I actually have no clue of what `whatever` could (or **should**) be.

Do you have any advice or guidance ?

For the technical part, I will probably code this in JS (with a NodeJS server).
But as I'm talking about the **concept** of *security code generation*, **any pseudo-code will do the job**.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a hash of the person's email address (capitalized) and make the code the first n-characters. So, for example, if your email address is TOUPYE@GMAIL.COM then the SHA-256 hash would be: `038122aedbf777b8c7c3aaed14ae7c08249a9d47f82f4455a0d667cacc57d383` so your code would be "038122". Generate a list of codes for each person/family. If someone has no email address use the telephone number. If they do not have a telephone, use their address.